# How to purge any persisted state using react tool kit with redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

In the official documentation it says to add an extra reducer in order to purge the state of the current slice, however there is no a clear example everywhere

```
import { PURGE } from "redux-persist";

extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(PURGE, (state) => {
    customEntityAdapter.removeAll(state);
  });
}
```

How to import or where did it get **customEntityAdapter**, when I call the `persistorObject` then purge it shows error, anybody can give me some light on this, thanks I appreciate clear example with redux-toolkit with https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist

Comment: ` persistor.purge().then(() => {
    persistor.flush();
    persistor.pause();
    persistor.persist();
  });` Only this worked for me

Answer (score 7):

As Radu Lunasu said, this is the correct code:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(PURGE, () => {
    return initialState;
  });
},
```

Then you can use persistor.purge() in any component, for exaple:

```
const handleLogout = () => {
    persistor.purge();
    navigate("/login");
};
```

I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer. Sorry, but +1

Comment: haha, but I did upvote yours :).

Answer (score 1):

The way that I approached this using `AsyncStorage` and `redux-persist` was to call the `persistor.purge()` when the user clicks to sign out, and then in the `extraReducers` add a case for `PURGE` that returns the inial state for each slice that you want to remove. `redux-persist` saves everything under the `persist:root` key in local storage.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { PURGE } from 'redux-persist';
...

extraReducers: builder => {
  builder
   .addCase(PURGE, () => {
     // When user logs out, clear the store
     AsyncStorage.removeItem('persist:root');
     return initialState;
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`customEntityAdapter`, according to its name, it should be created by [createEntityAdapter](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter).

> A function that generates a set of prebuilt reducers and selectors for performing CRUD operations

Whether it is used or not has nothing to do with using `redux-persist`. Since your question is about how to use RTK and `redux-persist`, and its purge state function, in order to simplify the problem, I will not use `createEntityAdapter`.

An example about how to use RTK with `redux-persist` and `.purge()` method on `persistor`.

`App.tsx`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { persistor } from "./store";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          persistor.purge();
        }}
      >
        purge state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`reducers.ts`:

```
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: (state = { name: "teresa teng" }, action) => state
});

export default rootReducer;
```

`store.ts`:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER]
      }
    })
});

let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

import { store, persistor } from "./store";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

The state persisted in the default storage engine - `localStorage`:

[image]

You can click the button, purge the state from `localStorage`.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-redux-persist-purge-67e1o)

Comment: this doesn't purge data from memory, only from localStorage. It is the aim of the PURGE case in extraReducers to delete the data in the memory store

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@slideshowp2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6463558/slideshowp2) answer's
the extra reducer to purge should match the config used to persist the state.
Change customEntitiyAdapter to storage mode specified in the persistConfig, which in this case is storage, change removeAll to remove, and speciify the key from the same persistConfig.
If the persistConfig is this

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage
};
```

change

```
import { PURGE } from "redux-persist";

extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(PURGE, (state) => {
    customEntityAdapter.removeAll(state);
  });
}
```

to

```
import { PURGE } from "redux-persist";

extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(PURGE, (state) => {
    storage.remove("root");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use :

```js
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

const store = {}

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export const purgeData = async () => {
  await persistor.purge();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

man, I did this and it worked. put this thing in your slice:

```
import { PURGE } from "redux-persist";

extraReducers: (builder) => {
  builder.addCase(PURGE, (state) => {
    customEntityAdapter.removeAll(state);
  });
}
```

then create a function in any component:

```
const purge = () => {
    persistor.purge()
}
```

use it where you need it:

```
<button onClick={purge}>Purge</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

that's just example code to reset state to initial state.
would be clearer if written like this:

```
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(PURGE, (state) => {
      return initialState;
    });
  },
```

remember, a reducer returns the new state therefore, after a purge, you would return the initial state or an empty state.